# React js filter not working correctly it won't return items when deleting characters

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Im trying to create a filter function based on the user input. The filter works fine but it won't return items when I delete characters. I know it has something to do with updating the state. I hope someone can help me out.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Link } from "react-router-dom";

class Fetch extends Component {
  constructor(){
    super();
    this.state = {
      data: []
    }

    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this)
  }

  handleChange = (event) => {
    console.log(event.target.value);
    return this.setState({data: this.state.data.filter(data => data.title.toLowerCase().includes(event.target.value.toLowerCase()))})
  }

  async componentDidMount() {
    try {
    const response = await fetch(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos`);
    const json = await response.json();
    this.setState({ data: json }); 
    }
    catch (error) {
      console.error(error)
    }
  }

  render() {
    return(
        <div>
          <p><Link to={`/`}>Link to homepage</Link></p>
          <form>
            <input type="text" onChange={this.handleChange}></input>
          </form>
          <ul>
            {
              this.state.data.map(data => (
                <li key={data.id}>{data.id} => {data.title}</li>
              ))
            }
          </ul>
        </div>
    )
  }
}
export default Fetch;
```

Comment: why do you have `data => data.title.toLowerCase().includes(event.target.value.toLowerCase().indexOf(event) > -1)` ? I think it should be `data => data.title.toLowerCase().includes(event.target.value.toLowerCase())` ?

Comment: Forgot to remove that your right!

Answer (score 0):

It is because you don't keep the initial data obtained from the HTTP request. Here is the problem:

1. Initially state: `data = []`
2. ComponentDidMount: `data = ['abc', 'bcd', 'cdf']`
3. Filter for keyword `b`: `data = ['abc', 'bcd']` (as `cdf` does not contain the letter `b`)
4. Erase the filter (`filter = ''`) but your data variable has the value `data = ['abc', 'bcd']`, so it can return at most 2 values.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following solution to solve your problem:

```
this.setState({ data:  this.state.data.filter(data => data.title.toLowerCase().indexOf(event.target.value.toLowerCase().trim() !== -1) ) })
```

Comment: You should keep a copy of data so that when you filter it is not overridden. Also there's no point in returning this.setState, remove the return. `this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this)` is also not needed since you are using arrow function for your methods

Comment: This answer has multiple issues: it does not explain what the question's author did wrong and why, the code is poorly formatted and is it now recommended that `setState` takes a callback function instead of the new state directly. Please edit your answer.

Comment: @ClémentPrévost , it isn't a callback. It's just based on what he did. filter will returns a list which is then given as a value to data. We could have assigned `this.state.data.filter(data => data.title.toLowerCase().indexOf(event.target.value.toLowerCase().trim() !== -1) )` to a variable say filtered list so that we set the state by doing `this.setState({ data: filteredList })`

Answer (score 0):

your code looks fine, but your filter function is overwriting the state's `data` property. I suggest storing the full array in `data` (as you are right now) and store the filtered results in another property of the state, something like this:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Link } from "react-router-dom";

class Fetch extends Component {
  constructor(){
    super();
    this.state = {
      data: [], 
      filtered: [] // This will store your filtered elements from data
    }

    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this)
  }

  handleChange = (event) => {
    console.log(event.target.value);
    // Filter the array stored in data, but never update it. 
    // Update filtered instead.
    return this.setState({filtered: this.state.data.filter(data => data.title.toLowerCase().includes(event.target.value.toLowerCase()))})
  }

  async componentDidMount() {
    try {
    const response = await fetch(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos`);
    const json = await response.json();
    // Keep the original data here.
    this.setState({ data: json }); 
    }
    catch (error) {
      console.error(error)
    }
  }

  render() {
    return(
        <div>
          <p><Link to={`/`}>Link to homepage</Link></p>
          <form>
            <input type="text" onChange={this.handleChange}></input>
          </form>
          <ul>
            {
              this.state.filtered.map(data => (
                <li key={data.id}>{data.id} => {data.title}</li>
              ))
            }
          </ul>
        </div>
    )
  }
}
export default Fetch;
```

Remember that `filter` don't modify the original array,it always returns a new one.